# change date format in r

Tags: r, date, zoo

a small problem here with a newbie R coder.

I have a zoo series which looks like this:

```
              EBO.NZ      MOW.NZ      RNS.NZ       RYM.NZ      SPN.NZ
Nov 2013 -0.026111144  0.09531018  0.00000000  0.026145280  0.01801851
Dec 2013  0.036367644 -0.26966357  0.00000000  0.012820688 -0.06771817
Jan 2014 -0.005115101  0.00000000 -0.28768207  0.006349228  0.10854017
Feb 2014  0.026317308  0.00000000  0.15415068  0.000000000 -0.01729150
Mar 2014  0.023693112 -0.04879016  0.00000000  0.102190941  0.01729150
Apr 2014 -0.086568016  0.00000000 -0.07410797 -0.011494379  0.00000000
May 2014  0.018967903  0.00000000  0.07410797 -0.038897066  0.00000000
Jun 2014  0.051867242  0.22314355  0.00000000  0.027269028 -0.01149438
Jul 2014 -0.008959741 -0.22314355  0.00000000 -0.018890762  0.01149438
```

I want the dates to be in this format (30-11-2013). Can anyone help?

Comment: There isn't information about the day of the month in your data set. Should an answer just assume that it's the thirtieth day? If so, what to do with February?

Comment: I suppose he thought last day of the month but did not write it.

Comment: Hm, it's not a trivial task to get the last day of the month. It would probably involve getting the first day of the next month, then counting 1 day backward.

Comment: My apologies guys. I should have been clearer. It is fine to go either ways: first or last day of the month.

Comment: You should instead apologize for posting a zoo object in its output format rather then the far more preferable result from: `dput(object)`. I find making zoo objects from scratch to be a complete PITA.

Comment: Did not realize it would be such a pain. As I said before, newbie here and trying to learn. You, on the other hand, could have asked for it...or even better...not do anything to help, rather than taking that tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first made (with some difficulty) a zoo object that looks like that and then this works:

```
> as.Date( as.yearmon(time(dat2)), frac=1)

[1] "2013-11-30" "2013-12-31" "2014-01-31" "2014-02-28" "2014-03-31"
[6] "2014-04-30" "2014-05-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-07-31"
```

Assignment with `time.zoo<-` then works as expected:

```
> time(dat2) <- as.Date( as.yearmon(time(dat2)), frac=1)
> dat2
                 EBO.NZ      MOW.NZ      RNS.NZ       RYM.NZ      SPN.NZ
2013-11-30 -0.026111144  0.09531018  0.00000000  0.026145280  0.01801851
2013-12-31  0.036367644 -0.26966357  0.00000000  0.012820688 -0.06771817
2014-01-31 -0.005115101  0.00000000 -0.28768207  0.006349228  0.10854017
2014-02-28  0.026317308  0.00000000  0.15415068  0.000000000 -0.01729150
2014-03-31  0.023693112 -0.04879016  0.00000000  0.102190941  0.01729150
2014-04-30 -0.086568016  0.00000000 -0.07410797 -0.011494379  0.00000000
2014-05-31  0.018967903  0.00000000  0.07410797 -0.038897066  0.00000000
2014-06-30  0.051867242  0.22314355  0.00000000  0.027269028 -0.01149438
2014-07-31 -0.008959741 -0.22314355  0.00000000 -0.018890762  0.01149438
```

See `help(as.Date, pack=zoo)`. There is also an as.Date for the `yearqtr`-class.

Comment: The hard part (demonstrating how to get Date values at the end of the intervals)  is done. Wrapping that Date-vector in format(., "%something") is trivial.

Comment: that is absolutely brilliant! thanks so much. there is just so much to learn. I could not put an up-vote as I am still not eligible. but that was very helpful!

Comment: If you cannot upvote, you can at least use the checkmark since it's your question.

Comment: @BondedDust He said it could also be the first of the month, so your hard part was actually unnecessary. I left the comment because ```format()``` converts the vector to character, which may mess with how a zoo object works.

Comment: @Reed: So you should have tested and then posted a format based result along the lines of `format(as.Date(as.yearmon(time(dat))), "01-%m-%Y")`. So why didn't you? I was working (building test case, searching for documentation and prior work on SO and R-help archives, testing code) on the end-of-month task before the clarification came.in.)

Comment: @Reed: Furthermore, the index of of a zoo object can be any of : character , numeric, or POSIXt-object. The qualifying criterion is ability to have ordering. See: `?zoo`

Comment: @BondedDust Sorry, my comment apparently came off a little strong. I hadn't gotten to that point in my own answer. The OP accepted yours after all, so that's good enough for me.